# How to switch places of 2 characters in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to space and character after it switch places in Python. An example input:

```
"Hell oWorld"
```

The expected output:

```
"Hello World"
```

**I tried to run the following code:**

```
text = "Hell oWorld"
text = list(text)
for x in range(len(text)):
    if text[x] == " ":
        text[x], text[x + 1] = text[x + 1], text[x]
text = "".join(text)
```

But it resulted into `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are continously swapping the space forward until the string end is reached. `break` out of for-loop after first match.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: The error occurs because your loop iterates for the full length of your text. But in the last iteration, the loop will try to access text[x+1] which is out of range.

Try to adjust the range to.

> for x in range(len(text)-1):

Comment: Don't use `list` as a name for variables, there's already a built-in with that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've got sound advice in the comments, an alternative solution, it might be easier to use a regular expression using the `.sub` method with capturing groups.

```
import re 
s = 'Hell oWorld'

subbed = re.sub('(\s)(\w)', r'\2\1',s)
```

---

```
print(subbed)

'Hello World'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
s = "Hell oWorld"
result, *rest = s.split()

for word in rest:
    result += f"{word[0]} {word[1:]}"
```

Result:

```
Hello World
```